# how to add multiple sytleSpan in single editText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, styles

I'm working with with `editText` and `buttons` and layout contains **four** buttons

1. btnBold
2. btnItalic
3. btnStrike
4. btnUnderline

and one `editText` **etDescription**

Now, here I'm styling my `editText's selected text` by clicking on buttons

**with using this code**

```
CharacterStyle styleBold, styleItalic, styleUnderline, styleStrike;

 styleBold = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
 styleItalic = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
 styleUnderline = new UnderlineSpan();
 styleStrike = new StrikethroughSpan();


 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnItalic:
                makeIt(styleItalic);
                break;

            case R.id.btnBold:
                makeIt(styleBold);
                break;

            case R.id.btnUnderline:
                makeIt(styleUnderline);
                break;
            case R.id.btnStrike:
                makeIt(styleStrike);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void makeIt(CharacterStyle characterStyle) {
        String wholeTextUnder = etDescription.getText().toString();
        int startu = etDescription.getSelectionStart();
        int endu = etDescription.getSelectionEnd();

        SpannableStringBuilder sbu = new SpannableStringBuilder(wholeTextUnder);

        sbu.setSpan(characterStyle, startu, endu, 0);
        etDescription.setText(sbu);
    }
```

It's giving my whole `editText` a `single style`

Like when i select text **1-10** and then make it's **bold** it works!

but, when i select other text then make it some other like `italic`, `strike`, `underline` then pervious text become normal and new changes successfully.

**I want that perivous text will also stay same**

Waiting for answer!

Thanks in advance!!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is when you call `String wholeTextUnder = etDescription.getText().toString();` You already change it to `String` it means any `Span` you set will be clear. Try this.

```
private void makeIt(CharacterStyle characterStyle) {
    CharSequence wholeTextUnder = etDescription.getText();
    int startu = etDescription.getSelectionStart();
    int endu = etDescription.getSelectionEnd();

    SpannableStringBuilder sbu = new SpannableStringBuilder(wholeTextUnder);

    sbu.setSpan(characterStyle, startu, endu, 0);
    etDescription.setText(sbu);
}
```

Comment: Can you please also told me how to get `spannable text` and `etDescription.getText().toString();` is giving me simple text without any style

Comment: What do you mean? You want to know why method toString is giving text without style right?